# Cakephp manual theme not working on server

Tags: cakephp

I am fresh in cake. I developed a site in cakephp that is working very well on my localserver but my manual theme is not working on live server. here is the website: http://www.enforcementindia.com/ is my URL.

on routs

```
<?php Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Sites', 'action' => 'index'));?>
```

on app model

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('RequestHandler','Session');
public $helpers = array('Form','Html','Js');
public $view   = 'themed';
public $theme = 'default';
}
?>
```

and my theme is located app\View\themed\default here any idea
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by manual theme ?

Comment: @Moyed Ansari I had created another layout which is located in app\View\themed\default where my header and footer saved for every page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Layout not theme

you will need to put you layout in view/Layouts folder.

all the footer/ header/ siders ... these small elements should be in view/Elements

**rout** is not related to this question

remove this lines from app controller
public $view   = 'themed';
public $theme = 'default';

Layou should be assigned inside your method e.g. SitesController.mysite

```
class SitesController extends AppController {
      public function mysite(){
      //here where you have to set your Layout
      $this->layout = 'name of layout you have created';
      }
}
```

then when you create your mysite view in View/Sites/mysite you will be able to see you layout